# What package and function to use to get a response that can be formatted in JSON after sending a query string

Tags: python, aws-lambda, urllib3, python-requests-html

I am currently using AWS Lambda which does not support the "requests" package. Hence I am trying to look for alternatives using urllib3

My code using the "requests" package is as such:

```
site_dict = {
'1':'JSDOKAJDISADK',
'2':'IOASJD8917238ASDW',
'3':'UIO2NKDNAK123'
for sId in site_dict:
params = {
    'api_key': site_dict[sId]
}
r = requests.get(url = id_url, params = params)
data = r.json()
```

Params is a dictionary where the
Using urllib3:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url=id_url, headers=params)
data = r.json()
```

However, I get the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\API Test.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = r.json()
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'
```

How do I get my data which I can then format into JSON format using urllib3?

Comment: Use `r.data` instead of `r.json()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `r.data` instead of `r.json()`

```py
...
data = r.data # and not r.json()
```

If you want to get Json content you have to use python json module

#### JSON Content

JSON content can be loaded by decoding and deserializing the data attribute of the request:

```py
import json
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

r = http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/ip')

json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
{'origin': '127.0.0.1'}
```

For more info read the [official documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html).